# Nvidia Nsight - how to connect to localhost?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cuda, nvidia, nsight

I'm trying to set up "localhost" as a connection name for Nsight (I'm using CUDA 4.2 with Nsight 2.2 on VS2010) but there's something like "localhost overridden to global connection name" which changes my localhost 127.0.0.1 address to another wrong one.

[image]

How can I solve this? I want to do local debugging

Comment: That other wrong one is more than likely your computer's address within the network. Especially since it's of the form 192.168.1.*

Comment: It is not, my address is 192.168.1.100

Comment: Gah, okay. Why would it pick up that other one then? (You of course didn't map your localhost to that IP in a hosts file? Stupid question, but just making sure.) Never used it in a local setup, so I don't have an idea then. I should try it.

Comment: I checked it in the first place, seems that I didn't nor anyone else did it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not have Nsight 2.2 because i am already on 3.0 RC1 so i can not tell for sure but this problem happened when i changed the connection name in the "Nsight Connections" toolbar. You can display/hide the toolbar for example by going to the View/Toolbars menu in VS and checking/un-checking the check-box "Nsight Connections". 
Once you see the toolbar, you can click the "Use global connection name" button to disable it.

Answer (score 1):

do you start the monitor service?
press start and search for it and run it.
also you might consider upgrading to CUDA 5 and nsight 3 as it is more usable and easier to use.

Comment: I did, I'll try with CUDA 5 and nsight 3 and let you know

Comment: as a note it is nsight visual studio edition now, you can download it from [link](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-nsight-visual-studio-edition)